# Echo arrays with regular text

Tags: php, arrays

How would I write this so I'm only using one echo?

```
echo "<div class='post'>";
echo $row['title'];
echo "</div>";
```

I'm using an array to echo out a table's values but it would be a lot easier on the eyes if I could combine these into one echo statement. However, when I try to the page goes blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the array reference in brackets:

```
echo "<div class='post'{$row['title']}</div>";
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way to accomplish my task. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<div class=\"post\">{$row['title']}</div>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Other ways of doing the same thing:

```
echo '<div class="post">'.$row['title'].'</div>';

echo sprintf('<div class="post">%s</div>', $row['title']);

<div class="post"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></div>
```

Comment: +1 for the last one. Separating HTML and PHP is the better way.

Comment: Agreed, but codedude did specifically indicate the use of echo and there are use cases for this.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to close the div

```
> echo "<div class='post'"; should be
> echo "<div class='post'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<div class="post">' . $row['title'] . '</div>';`

The `.` operator concatenates strings. Also, I believe HTML wants you to use double quotes for `class="post"` (although perhaps it doesn't care?).

Comment: Why concatenate when you can interpolate?

Comment: To speed it up, use a comma instead of a period. Also, use single quotes around your strings.

Comment: Habit, I suppose.  Why interpolate when you can concatenate?

Comment: Also, try to avoid using single quotes (`'`) for HTML attribute values, use `"` instead.

Comment: Indeed.  I had copied OP's text originally.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<div class='post'".$row['title']."</div>";
?>
```