# Echo regular text and arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo regular text along with arrays.  I'm basing the below code off of the answer found here, but it's not working: [Echo arrays with regular text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494117/echo-arrays-with-regular-text)

```
<?php
$val1 = Yes;
if (($row->relation) == ($val1)) {
echo "<p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b> {$row['relation_name']} | <b>Business:</b> {$row['relation_business']}</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is `$row` an object or an array?  What is the output?

Comment: var_dump($val1, $row->relation); Do they compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing so many thing wrong here

Example

```
        V--------------------- Row Seems to be Object here
 if (($row->relation) == ($val1)) {
  echo "<p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b> {$row['relation_name']}
                                       ^---------------------- Calling it as array here
```

After you clarify the above you can just use `printf` instead

If its `array` :

```
printf("<p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b> %s|<b>Business:</b>%s</p>",$row['relation_name'],$row['relation_business']);
```

If its `Object`

```
printf("<p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b>%s|<b>Business:</b>%s</p>",$row->relation_name,$row->relation_business);
```

Comment: an alternative would be to use echo using ',' eg: echo "myString: ", $variable; I believe this avoids the concatenation overheads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` notation which is clearly used for concatenation in `php`:

```
<?php
    $val1 = Yes;
    if (($row->relation) == ($val1)) {
        echo "<p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b>" . $row['relation_name'] . |  . "<b>Business:</b>" . $row['relation_business'] . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

or you can seperate `HTML` and `PHP` like this:

```
<?php
    $val1 = Yes;
    if (($row->relation) == ($val1)) {
?>
    <p><b>Applicant\'s Name:</b><?php echo $row['relation_name'] ?>|<b>Business:</b><?php echo $row['relation_business'] ?></p>      
<?
    }
?>
```